# Can an individual have multiple credit scores from different credit rating agencies?

Tags: credit-score, credit-rating-agency

As an individual, is it possible to have two different credit scores if rated by two different agencies, just as a corporation can have different credit ratings based on the rating agency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very likely that you will have different credit scores for the different companies. keep in mind the different companies have different algorithms. Also some creditors may not report information to the different companies. It is possible that a mistake doesn't appear in all the companies, thus giving different results.

Also remember that your score can change everyday, because some of the numbers used are a snapshot. Your credit utilization changes with every charge, and every payment; but is only reported to the credit agencies monthly. If you have multiple cards, loans, lines of credit, the utilization rate might change several times a month.

Comment: +1, minor correction - Utilization snapshot occurs when a bill is cut. e.g. I pay my bill in full the day the bill will be cut, my utilization is 0%, even though I used nearly the full credit line up to that point. The card issuer only sends the data in after the bill is cut.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer made suggested adjustment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact it is more likely than not that your scores will be somewhat different among different agencies. But they should not be radically different.

Comment: Untrue, you can have radically different scores between different bureaus based on where you live. For example, if you are a US-WEST person, your Experian will be the most detailed and as such might have radically lower score if you have defaults than Equifax or Trans Union who may or may not get reported to by the delinquent account. Just saying, while not always, it CAN happen and DOES.

Comment: Thanks, good point and interesting info. Proving once again there are always exceptions to "should", so caveat emptor.

Comment: Of course Bob, always an exception :)